# Selecting an image without a Class or ID using Javascript only

Tags: javascript

Ok.. this could be a bit of a challenge. Basically I need to select an image and I want it to fade in and out every few seconds.

Under normal circumstances it would be fairly straightforward... but the problem is the site I'm working on has certain restrictions.

Firstly the image has no ID or class (only alt text, and I can’t edit this to add a class) - it is sitting in a table that does have classes but I can’t seem to work out how to drill down to select the specific image using Javascript.... the system also doesn’t support jQuery.

I can do it using CSS no problem: `TABLE.tableClass TD.tdClass IMG {}`
But unfortunately the system can only be viewed in IE7/8 so CSS3 isn’t an option to make the image blink.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it. The best was I can think of would be to select the table, then the td, then the first image within it... but I can’t seem to work out how this would be done in js.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to support IE7 (and 8)?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to find the element (or [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll) to get a list of *all* matched elements):

```
document.querySelector('TABLE.tableClass TD.tdClass IMG');
```

However, this isn't supported in IE 7. Nor is `getElementsByClassName()`...

You may want to consider dropping support for IE7 altogether. A lot of the major websites out there don't support IE7 any more. More and more sites / libraries are dropping support for IE*, too.

Comment: Unfortunately the system is pretty large and it would be a huge undertaking to make it support modern browsers... they're of the opinion that if its working in its current state it shouldn't be messed with! I wasn't aware of 'querySelector' but that sounds like exactly the sort of thing I'm after. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a go! :)

Comment: _"make it support modern browsers"_? You mean it would be a huge undertaking to install modern browsers? Installing chrome really isn't that much work. Just keep in mind the `querySelector` does _not_ work in IE7. (There basically isn't a decent way to do this in IE7)

Comment: Installing chrome isn't the issue, the issue is that the website completely falls apart when it is opened in chrome.. the majority of the features stop working. At the moment it only works in those older versions of IE and they don't want to change that :( I think the vast majority of users are on IE8 so I'll aim to get it working with it. (edit: just realised I'm probably confusing things by switch between 'website' and 'system' to describe the same thing.. sorry haha!)

Comment: You're going to have to start fixing that some time. Eventually, no system will support those older browsers any more.

Comment: NOT moving towards a better code-base is not an option!

Comment: I completely agree, it really needs to be done at some point, sooner rather than later, but unfortunately not a decision I can make! :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to write a CSS selector to target the specific IMG element you are after, you can always use `document.querySelector()`, or `document.querySelectorAll()` if there are several possible candidates.

```
var allImagesMatching = document.querySelectorAll('table.tableClass td.tdClass img');

for (var i = 0; i < allImagesMatching.length; ++i) {
    var imgElement = allImagesMatching[i];
    // Do stuff here...
}
```

Or, for just adressing the first matching:

```
var imgElement = document.querySelector('table.tableClass td.tdClass img');
// Do stuff here...
```